# If-else statement for images.setvisibilty

Tags: android, if-statement, visibility

i wanna ask about how can i do an if-statement using the code below? I have tried it and it give me an error; its say cannot convert void to bool. any suggestion?

```
if(images.setVisibility(View.GONE)){
Display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use below of the two codes:

1. if(images.getVisibility==view.GONE)
       {
           Display();
       }

the `getVisibility()` returns an integer.

you can also check with the integer code

i.e.

```
VISIBLE-0
GONE-8
INVISIBLE-4
```

2.

```
if(images.getVisibility==0)
//VISIBLE
if(images.getVisibility==4)
//INVISIBLE
if(images.getVisibility==8)
//GONE
```

Comment: when we can define constant of View like `View.GONE` , then why a static constant value liek 0,8,4.

Comment: These are just two ways. nothing else, the behavior is obviously same

Comment: I know but we should avoid the static constant value directly, because its not a good practice

Answer (score 2):

You need to get visibilty and check it..

```
 if(images.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
        Display();
 }
```

Comment: That what i asked the **DOWN VOTER**.. **Please give reason for your down voting**

Comment: @Tamanna i didnt do anything. i also confused. btw, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your code, `images.setVisibility()`  `images` must be instance of `View`. then use `View.getVisibility()` method

```
if(images.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
Display();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

```
if(images.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
            Display();
            }
```